# tensorflow: proper learning rate for "sigmoid" with "SGD" for MLP

Tags: tensorflow

currently I made a simple MLP with one hidden layer, softmax output layer (shape=[440,8196,8], label is sparse) with Tensorflow, and tried different settings, e.g. different activation functions, different optimizers. Most of the settings work fine and provide reasonable convergent cross-validation results, except the setting (sigmoid, SGD). I debugged with different learning rates from 1.0, 0.1, 0.001, to 0.0001, to 0.00001, and the training is still not working, which shows no convergence. This confused me because other settings work OK, e.g. (sigmoid, Adam, learning_rate=0.001), (tanh/elu/relu, SGD, learning_rate=0.008 and be halved at each epoch).

I believe that all the Tensorflow functionalities are fine since I tested such different settings with MNIST data, and everything makes sense.
Why only (sigmoid, SGD) does not work in my solely case (my own data)??? 
From my limited experience, "sigmoid" usually can even endure a bit larger learning rate than "tanh". I changed different initialization schemes (constant, uniform), but still can not find where the problem is. Any suggestions to further debug? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with a single-layer network with one or 2 units to test out (sigmoid, SGD) first and then gradually increase the network complexity. This way you could better separate algorithmic issues and tensorflow usage/implementation issues.

Comment: thanks, Yao. yes, I tested a bit of my python codes with MNIST, and (sigmoid, SGD) worked fine as other settings. then I started to train my own data, and then came across this problem. I am sure that the implementation is OK, but confused why only (sigmoid, SGD) did not converge?! is it too sensitive to initialization parameters or how to properly fine-tune the learning rate?